# Mysql has gone away error randomly

Tags: mysql, php, tcp, connection, pdo

I have a web application written in php. In this app, I have a script(CLI) which is really heavy. After this script finishes its job, I get "mysql has gone away" error in my normal http request for a few minutes. For example, Last time my script finished its job around 22:38 and I was getting "mysql has gone away" for next 3 minutes.

This is the connections to mysql server(Mysql data):

[image: Mysql Connections]

And connections to mysql(using something like netstat):

[image: Mysql connections]

P.S: most of http request manage to open connection to mysql without any problems.

P.S: After a few minutes, I stop getting this error(22:42 in the chart).
P.S: I get this error when opening a connection using php's PDO or when I want to execute a statement.

P.S: CPU usage is quite normal

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you check the manual? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html

Comment: @LucasRamage Yes I have

Comment: You need to provide relevant information, then. Just saying you read the manual is not sufficient.

Comment: This can happen if a query choke your mysql (cpu or the disk). Please include a CPU chart & IO latency chart for the server, it might answer your question.

Comment: I suggest to ask rather "how to debug it".

Comment: @peterh I'm checking whether I can provide those charts I was asked for

Comment: @yagmoth555 I added those charts.